# check to see a child div has certain link in a parent DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="posts">
        <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="name" class="enabled"><a href="123.com/abc">User1</a></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div id="post-content">
                  Hello
              <div id="load">
              </div>
              </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
    <br><br>
            <table>
             <tr>
                <td>
                  <div id="name" class="enabled"><a href="123.com/user2">User2</a></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div id="post-content">
                      Hello too
                  <div id="load"></div>
                  </div>
                </td>
             </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
```

How can i use jQuery/Javacript to find link with "**abc**" inside **#name** div of **#posts table**.

and after locating it (the link with abc). jQuery will add html content to #post-content #load div **of that table that has link with "abc" inside** ,using the html(); function in jQuery.

that means after adding my code will look like this :

```
 <div id="posts">
    <table>
     <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="name" class="enabled"><a href="123.com/abc">User1</a></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="post-content">
              Hello
          <div id="load">
            Some stuff is added here using html()
          </div>
          </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
<br><br>
        <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
              <div id="name" class="enabled"><a href="123.com/user2">User2</a></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div id="post-content">
                  Hello too
              <div id="load"></div>
              </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
```

while the #name with no link with "abc" which is the link with "user2" **will not** be affected or modifeid.

How can i do this?

I hope you understand.

Comment: `id`'s should be unique. You **must** enforce this on your page to be able to reliably refer to elements using the `#id` jQuery selector.

Comment: yes i know but in this case i dont want to use ID's . instead i want to find it via the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you fix the html and use classes:

```
$('.name a[href*="abc"]').closest('tr').find('.load').html('Some stuff is added here using html()');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find a tag with href containing 'abc'
2. Get parent tr
3. Find `#postcontent >#load` within this element

   ```
   var x = $('a[href*="abc"]');
   var b = x.parents('tr');
   var c = b.find('#post-content > #load');
   alert(c.html());
   ```